# Count number in cell which have both comma and dash in one cell

Tags: excel, vba

Example

In Cell "A2" I have 2,4,5,7-9

How do I count them by using formula or coding with vba

and count them as 2 4 5 7 8 9 which sum up value to 6

and return value in Cell "B2"

Comment: Why should the count return 6 in your example 2,4,5,7-9?

Comment: I want a formula that count them as 2 4 5 7 8 and 9 and it's 6 number right? and sum it up to 6

Comment: And why didn't you mention that in your post? I'd suggest to edit your post accordingly and make it clearer to everyone what you are really after? BTW, what did you try to do it?

Comment: Sorry for didn't made a clear question at first. I just want to count the number in cell which my co-worker input data like this at the first place. It can't count with a simple countif which I made at first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming column `XFD` in the active sheet is empty, and that no integer within the string will ever exceed `2^20`:

`=SUM(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("XFD"&SUBSTITUTE(TEXTSPLIT(A2,","),"-",":XFD")),""))`

For those without `TEXTSPLIT`:

`=SUM(COUNTIF(INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(FILTERXML("<a><b>XFD"&SUBSTITUTE(A2,",","</b><b>XFD")&"</b></a>","//b"),"-",":XFD")),""))`

Comment: Sir, I don't have textsplit function. Do you have an alternative for this one?

Comment: @Eol Added an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Please, try the next function. It builds a virtual discontinuous range and count its cells:

```
Function countNumb(strNo As String) As Long
    Dim arr, i As Long
    
    arr = Split(Replace(Replace(strNo, " ", ""), "-", ":"), ",")
    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
        If Not InStr(arr(i), ":") > 0 Then
            arr(i) = arr(i) & ":" & arr(i)
        End If
    Next
    countNumb = Intersect(Range(Join(arr, ",")), Range("A:A")).cells.count
    Debug.Print Range(Join(arr, ",")).Address 'only to visually see the built range before intersection address...
End Function
```

It can also process a string as "2, 4,5,7 - 9"...

It can be tested using the next code:

```
Sub testCountNumbers()
    Dim x As String: x = "2,4,5,7-9"
    Debug.Print countNumb(x)
End Sub
```

Comment: Very clever & creative use of counting a virtual range `$A$2,$A$4:$A$5,$A$7:$A$9` as result of *intersecting* a joined array of numeric pairs (`2:2,4:4,5:5,7:9`) with a column - e.g. `Range("A:A")` +:) @FaneDuru

Answer (score 1):

With VBA,

```
Function AddNumbers(rngTarget As Range) As Long
    Dim arrValues() As String
    Dim lngValue As Long
    Dim strValue As String
    Dim lngMinimum As Long
    Dim lngMaximum As Long

    arrValues = Split(rngTarget.Text, ",")
    
    For lngValue = LBound(arrValues) To UBound(arrValues)
    
        strValue = arrValues(lngValue)
                
        If InStr(strValue, "-") > 0 Then
        
            lngMinimum = CLng(Left(strValue, InStr(strValue, "-") - 1))
            
            lngMaximum = CLng(Replace(strValue, lngMinimum & "-", vbNullString))
        
            AddNumbers = AddNumbers + ((lngMaximum - lngMinimum) + 1)
        
        Else
        
            AddNumbers = AddNumbers + 1
        
        End If
    
    Next lngValue
        
End Function
```

Comment: Correct solution for the above example (so UV) but it will fail for `2,4,5,7 -9`

Comment: There's any number of things that would make it fail, so unless error proofing is asked for, it won't be provided.

Comment: Fair enough. Good point! OP did not also mention what to do in case of `2,4,5,5-9`!

Comment: If every value had to be unique, a Collection would provide a solution, assuming other errors are thrown into the mix.